# Problems with DTC and IBM MQ

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, message-queuing, msdtc

I've just run DTC Ping to try to find the cause of a MQ problem.

It says the following:

```
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
10-18, 10:30:31.508-->Start DTC connection test
Name Resolution:
    SOMESERVERNAME-->172.1.2.3-->SOMESERVERNAME
10-18, 10:30:31.843-->Start RPC test (SOMECLIENTNAME-->SOMESERVERNAME)
RPC test is successful
    Partner's CID:15E66B7A-0F9D-4649-87B3-478163A5F06D
++++++++++++RPC test completed+++++++++++++++
++++++++++++Start DTC Binding Test +++++++++++++
Trying Bind to SOMESERVERNAME
10-18, 10:30:32.260-->SOMECLIENTNAME Initiating DTC Binding Test....
    Test Guid:41DFA125-465D-4AC1-8B22-CC94F0475816
Binding call to SOMESERVERNAME Failed
    In  GUID
    Out GUID
Session Down
```

"*Binding call to SOMESERVERNAME Failed*" doesn't say anything to me. And googling doesn't help (for instance [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/138d744b-9c37-40e7-bc7a-7dcd46936bfa) post).

Note that the MQ server and the client is in different domains (trust should have been configured between the domains).

---

**Update**

Other side says

```
++++++++++++Start Reverse Bind Test+++++++++++++
Received Bind call from SRT00428
Trying Reverse Bind to SRT00428
Error(0x6D9) at ServerManager.cpp @453
-->RPC reverse BIND failed
-->1753(There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.)
Reverse Binding to SRT00428 Failed
Session Down
```

Which kind of answers the question. Thanks for pointing out that the receiving DTC Ping can have logs too.

Comment: Do you have any logs on the remote server?  The server may have logged a more useful error message.

Comment: @Ladadadada: thanks ;) You can add that as an answer. (that the receiving DTC Ping have more logs).